# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, Swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

So i'm now trying to convert a NSDictionary stored in NSUserdefault to my array used for table contents, but i meet many many errors including "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", (The currently one)
Just wondering what's the most safe and correct way of converting it.

And here is my codes.

```
        let nsd:NSDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("storedPosts") as! NSDictionary
        for (postId, postInfo) in nsd{ //post id and the post
            let importedPost:Post = Post(postId: postId as! String, priorityLevel: postInfo.objectForKey("priorityLevel") as! String, status: postInfo.objectForKey("status") as! String, section: postInfo.objectForKey("section") as! String, userType: postInfo.objectForKey("userType") as! String, dataPosted: postInfo.objectForKey("dataPosted") as! String, lastUpdate: postInfo.objectForKey("lastUpdate") as! String, states: postInfo.objectForKey("states") as! String, personalizedToViewerData: postInfo.objectForKey("personalizedToViewerData") as! [String:Bool], content: postInfo.objectForKey("content") as! Dictionary<String, Any>)
        posts.append(importedPost)
}
```

Any sugguestions would be appreciated

Comment: First you need to absolutely **stop using force-unwrapping and force-downcasting with `!`**, you have to make everything safe with, for example, `if let ... = ... else ...` so that you can handle possible errors. Then if there's still an issue we'll help.

Comment: and if you're having trouble with something - don't keep all of your code in a single line - split it up into blocks and it will be much easier to debug

Comment: @EricD. Thx for your prompt reply, i will change it and edit the post

Comment: @Russell Yeap, i will follow Eirc's lead and see if i can figure out the problem

Comment: @EricD. I see that "if let" will test if it holds a value, but how do i safely know the value has the desired type?

Comment: Use conditional downcasting, like: `if let id = postId as? String {`. You can even do multiple ones on the same line if you want: `if let id = postId as? String, info = postInfo.objectForKey("priorityLevel") as? String {`  etc.

Comment: @EricD. Thx a lot, it solved most of my errors!!!, I will rephrase my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "force-unwrap" an Optional with `!`, you're telling the compiler "It's ok we can always unwrap because I know for sure there always will be a value".

But if there's actually no value, the app will crash...

So you have to first safely unwrap your Optionals.

There's a lot of techniques, the simplest for now is `if let`.

With "if let" you safely unwrap a value into a new constant, then you can use this new constant instead of the Optional. If you need to check the type or downcast, you can use "conditional downcasting" (the real name is "optional binding", I believe) with `if let xxx = yyy as? zzz`.

Let's see how we could do that:

```
if let nsd = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("storedPosts") as? NSDictionary {
    // use `nsd` here
}
```

Let's go further:

```
if let nsd = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("storedPosts") as? NSDictionary {
    for (postId, postInfo) in nsd {
        if let id = postId as? String {

        }
    }
}
```

It works, but we see that using an "if let" for every value would lead to a "pyramid of doom"...

A classic solution for this is to use multiple optional bindings with the same "if let":

```
if let nsd = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("storedPosts") as? NSDictionary {
    for (postId, postInfo) in nsd {
        if let id = postId as? String,
            priorityLevel = postInfo.objectForKey("priorityLevel") as? String,
            status = postInfo.objectForKey("status") as? String,
            section = postInfo.objectForKey("section") as? String {  // keep doing the same for all your values

            let importedPost = Post(postId: id, priorityLevel: priorityLevel, status: status, section: section, ...)  // etc

        }
    }
}
```

A nice side-effect is that you can now handle errors by adding an `else` branch to the "if let" conditions that need it.